# Delete incoming header X-Forwarded-For from client within Ingress (Cloud HTTPS Load Balancer)

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

How to delete / block header **X-Forwarded-For** coming from client for Ingress (Cloud HTTPS Load Balancer) within GKE?

Comment: What do you mean by how to delete the header? Why would you want to delete it? Simply ignore it in your application if you don't care. If you use a web framework which automatically parses that header then disable that feature or configure how many proxies you actually have between you and clients since you cannot trust this header.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you can try to use [Custom headers](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#target-proxies) for External HTTP(S) Load balancer.

> Custom request and response headers allow you to specify additional
> headers that the external HTTP(S) load balancer adds to requests and
> responses. These headers can include information that the load
> balancer detects about the client connection, including the latency to
> the client, the geographic location of the client's IP address, and
> parameters of the TLS connection.

You can find the way to apply it on GKE ingress according to this [example](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#request_headers):

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: my-backendconfig
spec:
  customRequestHeaders:
    headers:
    - "X-Client-Region:{client_region}"
    - "X-Client-City:{client_city}"
    - "X-Client-CityLatLong:{client_city_lat_long}"
```